# Display posts side by side with custom query

Tags: wp-query, loop, css, html

I'm trying to organize my posts side by side but they keep being displayed vertically.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row agenda-box justify-content-start padding minheight-40">
    <div class="col-md-6 padding-top padding-bottom">
        <h5 class="main-text section-title">próximos eventos</h5>
        <?php
        $agendaHome = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'artist',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => ASC,
        ));

        while ($agendaHome->have_posts()) {
            $agendaHome->the_post(); ?>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button class="agenda-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></button>
                    <div id="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="collapse">
                        <?php the_field('agenda'); ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        <?php }
        ?>


    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: most likely a css issue and not a WP issue.  does it work with just dummy content inside of the col-md-6

Comment: yes! it works perfectly without the php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your final html should look, but I guess it's:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

In that case, you should move the `ul` element outside the while loop and your code should look like this:

```
<ul>
<?php while ($agendaHome->have_posts()) {
            $agendaHome->the_post(); ?>
    <li>rest of the code goes here</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Also add apostrophes around ASC at the order parameter.

```
'order' => 'ASC'
```